# How can I serve json index properly over nginx?

Tags: json, nginx

I have the following `nginx.conf`:

```
events {}

http {
    server {
        index index.json;
        location /api/some-folder {
            alias /some-folder;
            default_type application/json;
            add_header Content-Type application/json;
        }
    }
}
```

With that in place, when the nginx docker image is served on port 8080 and has my json files packed in folder `/some-folder`, I can browse

```
http://localhost:8080/api/some-folder/
```

and I get the content of `/some-folder/index.json` back. Furthermore, when I browse

```
http://localhost:8080/api/some-folder/subfolder_1/subfolder_2/some-json.json
```

then I get the content of `/some-folder/subfolder_1/subfolder_2/some-json.json`. All fine.

My issue is that I can't seem to find a way to get the `/some-folder/index.json` content when I browse

```
http://localhost:8080/api/some-folder
```

with no trailing slash. When I browse that, I get redirected to

```
http://localhost/api/some-folder/
```

which doesn't exist, because nothing is served on port 80. I think I am missing something on how nginx works, and I'd appreciate some help to make it work.

If I simplify my location to just `/`, then the following configuration works perfectly with and without trailing slash:

```
events {}

http {
    server {
        index index.json;
        location / {
            root /some-folder;
            default_type application/json;
            add_header Content-Type application/json;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like the same behavior as that, but with a location `/api/some-folder`.

### EDIT

Please find [here](https://github.com/zadigus/nginx-json-issue) a github repository where the issue is reproduced.

Comment: You could add `absolute_redirect off;` so the redirection will work.

Comment: that doesn't work, I get redirected to http://localhost/api/some-folder/